# How to load div data while loading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I want to display div data before loading a merchant site.

JavaScript code:

```
       function two()
      {
         var newWin = window.open('URL');
//I want to load "<div class="loader"> content before the above URL loads in new window
      }
```

here is my HTML code :

```
      <div class="loader">I have some content and images which i wanted to dispaly in loading page</div>

   <input class="btn add-to-cart-btn" onclick="two();" type="button" value="More Info At {{ product.vendor }}"/>
```

How can i load div content ? Please let me know if anybody have suggestion.

Comment: What is exactly your purpose? To show something like 'Content is loading' and then load the actual content?

Comment: Can you provide some more info? What do you mean before loading the site? Does the user have to dismiss the div before the rest of the site loads? Can you explain the scenario a bit better?

Comment: customer will come to my site and they will click the button "more info at"  then the URL will open in New tab before loading that site i wanted display some content or image .